# PHP: Trying to get property of non-object, from BatchError object of Bing Ads API

Tags: php, yii2, bing-ads-api

I get this error when I try to view the error messages from the API. The documentation says it returns an array of BatchError objects in the PartialError field. When I try to access the Index property of BatchError, it gives me an error. What is wrong?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-campaign-management-addadgroups.aspx#Anchor_1

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object

1. in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/bestsales/models/BingAds.php at line 384

      $response = $campaignProxy->GetService()->AddAdGroups($request);
    } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
      $this->handleException($e);
      return null;
    }
    $adGroupsIds = $response->AdGroupIds;
    $partialErrors = $response->PartialErrors;
    foreach ($partialErrors as $batchError) {
      Yii::error($batchError);
      $adGroup = $adGroups[$batchError->Index]; # <<<<
```

Logs:

```
2016-09-11 22:15:59 [::1][1][v5adqit0fiae7bon3i1lks49m3][error][application] [
    unserialize('O:8:"stdClass":8:{s:4:"Code";i:1016;s:7:"Details";N;s:9:"ErrorCode";s:33:"CampaignServiceInvalidEntityState";s:9:"FieldPath";N;s:23:"ForwardCompatibilityMap";N;s:5:"Index";i:0;s:7:"Message";s:104:"Passed entity state is invalid. Please refer to documentation for list of valid values for given entity.";s:4:"Type";s:10:"BatchError";}'),
]
    in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/bestsales/models/BingAds.php:383
    in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/bestsales/models/AdGroup.php:195
    in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/bestsales/models/Keyword.php:145
2016-09-11 22:15:59 [::1][1][v5adqit0fiae7bon3i1lks49m3][error][yii\base\ErrorException:8] exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/bestsales/models/BingAds.php:384
```

I also tried

```
  Yii::error($batchError);
  Yii::error($batchError['Index']);
  Yii::error($batchError::$Index);
  Yii::error($batchError->$Index);
  Yii::error($batchError->Index);
```

I used [`VarDumper`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-vardumper.html) and got this:

```
[
    0 => stdClass#1
    (
        [Code] => 1016
        [Details] => null
        [ErrorCode] => 'CampaignServiceInvalidEntityState'
        [FieldPath] => null
        [ForwardCompatibilityMap] => null
        [Index] => 0
        [Message] => 'Passed entity state is invalid. Please refer to documentation for list of valid values for given entity.'
        [Type] => 'BatchError'
    )
]
```

Comment: What is `$adGroups`? As far as I can tell, there's no problem accessing `$batchError->Index`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with

```
$partialErrors = $response->PartialErrors;
if (!empty($partialErrors->BatchError)) $partialErrors = $partialErrors->BatchError;
foreach ($partialErrors as $batchError) {
```

Apparently `foreach` is able to loop over the properties of an object too, which I did know know it could do, and apparently `PartialErrors` is an object with one property named `BatchError` which *then* contains an array (but `BatchError` may also not exist at all). This doesn't match the documentation, or at least not the *documentation of least surprise*.